# I do not get my revenue filtered date wise in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I am a newbie in Power BI. I have created my data model with a Calendar Lookup table which consists of all dates since 2015 to current date and also a Sales table. I have sales entries for 2017 in Sales table. Now I want my Total Revenue gets filtered for a particular date. Suppose the date is 1/1/2017. And I have minimum 6 entries on that Order Date in Sales Table. The calculation I have done to get Total Revenue is -

```
Total Revenue =SUMX (Sales, Sales [Order Quantity] * Sales [Retail Price])
```

And now I want to filter this Total Revenue for 1st January 2017. I have chosen CALCULATE function to do that. I have tried this way -

```
Revenue on 1/1/2017 = CALCULATE ([Total Revenue],
                             Calendar [Date] = 1/1/2017)
```

But I do not get any answer. I have perfect relationship status between Sales and Calendar table. I have made a one-to-many relationships between Date in Calendar table and Order Date in Sales table. I can't understand what I am missing out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide your date value as below (YYYY,MM,DD):

```
Revenue on 1/1/2017 = CALCULATE ([Total Revenue], Calendar [Date] = DATE(2017,01,01))
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I shall try your suggestion tomorrow and let you know the outcome.